# Mongoose find time furthest from other times in db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a program that runs every 5 minutes and checks the last time a users data was updated.  If it's been greater than 4 hours an update routine is called but as the service grows, I've seen some spikes in the number of calls at given times.  I want to start spreading out the update times.  Since I know each time the program updated each users data last, I was wondering if there was an elegant way to find the largest gap between times and set the new users update time to that?

Here's an example.  Given the following data:

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "updatedAt": "2018-01-17T01:12:33.807Z"
},{
  "_id": "2",
  "updatedAt": "2018-01-17T03:17:33.807Z"
},{
  "_id": "3",
  "updatedAt": "2018-01-17T02:22:33.807Z"
},{
  "_id": "4",
  "updatedAt": "2018-01-17T02:37:33.807Z"
}
```

The largest time between the given updates is 1 hour and 10 minutes between id: 1 and id: 3.  I want a function that can find that largest gap of time and returns the a suggested update time for the next item added to the database of '2018-01-17T01:47:33.807Z'.  Which was calculated by taking the 1 hour and 10 minutes and dividing it by 2 and then adding it to id: 1's date.

I would also like to spread out all the existing users update time but I suppose that would be a different function.

Comment: Without some sample data and a more precise explanation it will be hard to answer your question...

Comment: @dnickless I updated my question with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use aggregation framework for a difference style comparison. However you can use map reduce to get the largest time diff between documents.

Something like

```
db.col.mapReduce(
  function () {
   if (typeof this.updatedAt != "undefined") {
     var date = new Date(this.updatedAt);
     emit(null, date);
     }
  },
  function(key, dates) {
     result = {"prev":dates[0].getTime(), "last":dates[0].getTime(), "diff":0}
     for (var ix = 1; ix < dates.length; ix++) {
        value = dates[ix].getTime();
        curdiff = value - result.prev;
        olddiff = result.diff;
        if(olddiff < curdiff)
        result = {"prev":value, "diff":curdiff, "last":result.prev};
     }
    return result;
  },
  { 
    "sort":{"updatedAt":1},
    "out": { "inline": 1 },
    "finalize":function(key, result) {
     return new Date(result.last + result.diff/2);
    }
  }
)
```

Aggregation query:

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"updatedAt":{"$exists":true}}},
  {"$sort":{"updatedAt":1}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":null,
    "dates":{"$push":"$updatedAt"}
  }},
  {"$project":{
    "_id":0,
    "next":{
      "$let":{
        "vars":{
          "result":{
            "$reduce":{
              "input":{"$slice":["$dates",1,{"$subtract":[{"$size":"$dates"},1]}]},
              "initialValue":{"prev":{"$arrayElemAt":["$dates",0]},"last":{"$arrayElemAt":["$dates",0]},"diff":0},
              "in":{
                "$cond":[
                  {"$lt":["$$value.diff",{"$subtract":["$$this","$$value.prev"]}]},
                  {"prev":"$$this","last":"$$value.prev","diff":{"$subtract":["$$this","$$value.prev"]}},
                  "$$value"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "in":{
          "$add":["$$result.last",{"$divide":["$$result.diff",2]}]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Do you mind posting a complete example?  I tried using your code and I got errors?  This is the error I'm getting `Cannot read property '0' of undefined at Listing.mapReduce.sort.updatedAt`

Comment: Np. I've verified the query with the provided data set. do you have documents without `updatedAt `field ?

Comment: I think I do, yeah, I started tracking updates as the load to the server increased so some of the old entries might not have it. Is it possible to check for that? Thanks!

Comment: Np. I've updated the answer to include aggregation query and updated map reduce solution. I've assumed dates being saved in ISODate type ( recommended for date calculations ) for aggregation solution. You can use `$dateFromString` ( 3.6 version ) to convert them into ISODate if you have dates stored as string. Something like `{"$push":{$dateFromString:"$updatedAt"}}`

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it out but I will.  I marked your post as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm finally getting a chance to work on this issue again.  I tried out `mapReduce` and I realized it using mongobg not mongoose.  Would you mind rewriting it for mongoose?  I tired but keep getting errors.

Comment: Here is an [map reduce example](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/tree/master/examples/mapreduce) from mongoose github. See if you use it. I can write for you if you face problems. Let me know